# adaptive cards : how to pass values and influence content on Show Card action from main card?

Tags: adaptive-cards

I have an adaptive card which has multiple input controls. and instead of submit I have show Details button on clicking of which I need to show the details based on inputs provided. Is there a way to refer to the values dynamically  and show the content of the details cards based on what is chosen in the main card?

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible.

The ShowCard contains the entire JSON payload of another complete card and since the cards are declarative, rather than dynamic, you need to know the ShowCard payload at the time you create the original JSON